# Bluemix container cf ic command --ip option not working

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

On Bluemix Container command line, when running command of below, the conatiner does not have the private IP specified.

cf ic run -m 512 -P --name cname --net default --ip  registry.ng.bluemix.net/image

Answer (score 0):

The --ip option isn't supported by IBM containers. There is no way to specify the private IP of the container; it is automatically assigned when the container is created. You can get the IP address of your container once it's started with the `cf ic inspect` command.

Refer to the cf ic run reference for a list of supported options: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__run

Alternatively, you can request and bind a public IP to your container. However, your container is made available on the Internet via this https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ips.html#container_cli_ips

Comment: Hey , I know you. I once contacted you for some bluemix support on Sametime!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given above, you can replace the IBM Containers default settings for the private container network and create your own custom subnet and private IP address range. This might be useful if your app requires an IP address from your company's internal network. See, https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_security_network.html#container_cli_ips_byoip